# link to user from services#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

when i try to link to users#show the id from the service become id for user
for example if i'm watching service with id 3 that a user with id 1 has created and want link service.user.name  take the id from service and will show me user with id 3

i have this in my view  services/show

```
<%= link_to @service.user.name, user_path %>
```

users controller

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

routes

```
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

thanks

Comment: what the question? what the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path:

```
user_path
```

needs to know *which* user you want to look at... you have to tell it which user eg:

```
link_to @service.user.name, user_path(@service.user)
```